# GDI+: unhandled exception when drawing bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

What I am doing is reading greyscale jpeg using turbojpeg, creating Gdiplus::Bitmap using its data and trying to draw it using Gdiplus::Graphics. Everything is fine up to the point where i try to draw the image - I get `Unhandled exception at 0x74123193 in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x04ac7848.` Bitmap is apparently created properly - `Bitmap::lastResult == Ok`. My code looks like this:

```
// Initialize GDI+.
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

// creating program window

Graphics = new Gdiplus::Graphics(GetDC(hwnd));
Graphics->SetCompositingMode( Gdiplus::CompositingModeSourceCopy );
Graphics->SetCompositingQuality( Gdiplus::CompositingQualityHighSpeed );
Graphics->SetPixelOffsetMode( Gdiplus::PixelOffsetModeNone );
Graphics->SetSmoothingMode( Gdiplus::SmoothingModeNone );
Graphics->SetInterpolationMode( Gdiplus::InterpolationModeDefault );

// loading jpeg using turbojpeg
std::vector<unsigned char> data;

int width, 
    height;

std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

long begin,end;
begin = (long)ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
end = (long)ifs.tellg();
long size = end - begin;
ifs.seekg(0);

std::vector<char> jpegdata(size);
unsigned char* dataptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&jpegdata[0]);
ifs.read(&jpegdata[0], jpegdata.size());
tjhandle handle = tjInitDecompress();
tjDecompressHeader(handle, dataptr, jpegdata.size(), &width, &height);
data.resize(width * height);
tjDecompress2(handle, dataptr, jpegdata.size(), &data[0], width, width, height, TJPF_GRAY, 0);
tjDestroy(handle);

// creating Gdiplus::Bitmap
Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(width, 
                                height, 
                                width * 8, 
                                PixelFormat8bppIndexed, 
                                (BYTE*)&data[0]);

// drawing bitmap
Graphics->DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
```

The exception is thrown at

```
Graphics->DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
```

What is the reason to this behavior? What am I doing wrong?

`edit`

Setting the correct stride as user1837009 suggested fixed the exception.

There's a reason I use this particular constructor - I need to have the image data as raw as possible, greyscale, 8 bits per pixel to do some transformations. And I'm fairly certain that's what I have in `data` variable after calling `tjDecompress2`. Unfortunatelly, it seems there's no 8 bit greyscale pixel format supported, only PixelFormat16bppGrayScale, which is 16 bits. Any ideas on how to go around this?

Comment: Try change stride in Bitmap constructor, because it take size in bytes, not bits. I.e: Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(width, height, width * 1, PixelFormat8bppIndexed,(BYTE*)&data[0]);

Comment: Slamming a 8bpp indexed pixel format on top of undecoded raw jpeg file content cannot possibly work.  Kaboom when the file size is too small, it always is.  Use Image::FromFile() instead, GDI+ already has a built-in jpeg decoder.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong here:

1. Jpeg files are complex files containing compressed data. You are reading the entire file in, and treating it as if it was a basic bitmap. That simply can not possibly work (it's similar to putting a CD on a old-fashioned vinyl grammophone, and wondering why it's not making any/the right sound).
2. The stride for a bitmap is the distance in bytes between one line of pixels and the next.
3. I don't believe, even if the jpeg data is correct, that your image will have the pixelformat `PixelFormat8bppIndexed`.

To fix 2 and 3 of the above points is pretty simple (use the right stride and the right pixelformat). To fix point 1 means that you have to read in the JPEG image in a sane way.

However, there is of course a much simpler solution: Use [`Bitmap.Bitmap(const WCHAR*, BOOL)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will load a JPEG image directly, without you having to deal with anything to do with "how to decode a JPEG image.

Comment: Well, then don't store it in JPEG in the first place. Or decode the JPEG content yourself, but bear in mind that DECODING jpeg doesn't change the pixel content, it's when storing the image (converting from a bunch of plain pixel to the compressed form) that causes data loss [as always subject to bugs of course - but bugs tend to show up as "big blobs of pixels are entirely wrong colour", not "the colour is 1% off"]. And if the image is 8 bits per pixel already, then it should work fine. If it's not a greyscale image, telling Windows that your lump of JPEG data IS, will only cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

read that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536315(v=vs.85).aspx

for stride param.

So try,

Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(width, 
                                height, 
                                width, 
                                PixelFormat8bppIndexed, 
                                (BYTE*)&data[0]);